# Macbook Pro can't detect bootable USB with Yosemite

Tags: hard-drive, usb

I created a Yosemite boot USB, from the App Store version 10.10.1.

When I hold option during Boot, the USB drive doesn't show up on the menu.

I have an aluminium MBP, bought in 2009. It is the full body aluminium with the Superdrive.
The only drives I see when holding down option are Macintosh HD and Recovery. When I try to run recovery, it runs for a little and then goes to a "no" symbol, with the spinner still spinning. I am concerned that the HD may be dead/dying, but I don't want to jump to that conclusion yet.

How do I either boot to my USB, or just get a restore done?

Comment: How did you create the USB drive?

Comment: Please post an answer below so others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the pram by doing the following:

Shut down the Mac.
Locate the following four keys: option, command, p and r. You'll need them in the next step.
Power on the Mac, then immediately hold option, command, p and r. You need to do this before the grey screen appears.
Hold down the keys until you hear the startup sound twice, then release them.
Plug in the bootable USB stick, restart the Mac, and hold option.
I can't guarantee that it'll work, but it won't hurt, so it's worth a try.